# CSS to overlay centered text on a background image

Tags: html, css

I'm not an html/css guy but the guy who usually does this quit so it fell into my lap.

I have a page where there is a background image to fill the entire page. I found some sample css online to do this:

```
html {
        background: url(background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

What I want to do now is overlay some text on this such that it appears at the centered at the bottom of the page (not right at the bottom, maybe 50 px up from bottom). I tried a bunch of things but can't seem to get it quite right.

Comment: "I tried a bunch of things" ... what have you tried? Maybe you were already close ;)

Comment: @lumio Like text-align:center; display:inline-block absolute positioning then using bottom, I dunno, I'm not a front end guy, this stuff is greek to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what your goal is you can use a combination of `position: absolute` and set the `bottom` and `left` attribute, like so:

```css
body {
  background: skyblue;
}

.footer-text {
  display: block; /* just so IE will correctly render it */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer-text">footer text</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<body>    
  <div class="bottomme">
    <p>I'm some text at the bottom of the page</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
html 
{
   background: url(https://astrobioloblog.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/duck-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  font-size:16px;
    }

body
{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:flex-end;
}

.bottomme
{
  font-size:3rem;
  line-height:1.25em;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:1em;
  border:1px solid blue;
}
```

background-position: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position

push div to bottom of page: https://codepen.io/carolmckayau/pen/bmaOyK

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the code, my suggestion would be to add the text in it's own tag (e.g. a p-tag `<p>your text here</p>` ) and then position the text with

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 50%; /* Depending on how low/high you want the text */
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

W3schools.com has a great example on this right here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp